# Problemas em transformar .py para .exe do meu projeto de reconhecer imagens com opencv

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, pyinstaller, cx-freeze

Eu tenho um projeto de reconhecer imagens usando opencv, separei ele em 3 pacotes mais o código da interface gráfica em tkinter que controla a ativação. Ele funciona normalmente, mas quando transformo para .exe da erro de execução (usei pyinstaller, auto-py-to-exe, cx_Freeze e sempre o mesmo). Segue meu código principal:

```
from tkinter import *
from Bot import play
from PIL import Image, ImageTk


bo = False


def loop():
    if bo:
        play.bot()
    root.after(750, loop)


def eventstart():
    global bo
    bg.config(image=img2)
    bstart.forget()
    bstop.pack(side=TOP)
    bo = True


def eventstop():
    global bo
    bo = False
    bg.config(image=img1)
    bstop.forget()
    bstart.pack(side=TOP)


root = Tk()


bo = False
root.wm_attributes("-topmost", 1)
root.geometry('300x200+0+0')
root.title('BOTFT')
root.iconbitmap('FindObjects/Images/Icon/icon.ico')
img1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("FindObjects/Images/Background/bg1.png"))
img2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("FindObjects/Images/Background/bg2.png"))
bg = Label(root, image=img1)
frame = Frame(root)
bstart = Button(frame, text='Start', width=8, height=7, command=lambda: eventstart())
bstop = Button(frame, text='Stop', width=8, height=7, command=lambda: eventstop())
bsett = Button(frame, text='Settings', width=8, height=2)
bg.pack(side=LEFT)
frame.pack(side=RIGHT)
bstart.pack(side=TOP)
bsett.pack(side=BOTTOM)


root.after(750, loop)
root.mainloop()
```

A função play, no pacote Bot, executa varias funções do modulo Find, que está dentro do Pacote FindObjects. Dentro do FindObjects também estão todas as imagens que estão dentro do pacote Images, que também tem o modulo com funções que tira screenshots e armazena na pasta Screenshots dentro de Images. Além disso tem um pacote de ferramentas onde defino funções para usar opencv, pywin32, etc. com mais facilidade. Tenho alguns modulos e pacotes, posso não estar entendendo como juntar tudo isso em um exe.